# Matched Pairs, GEE Models, and Other Regression Models

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, matching, generalized-estimating-equations

I am presenting the following hypothetical example in which the variables may or may not make sense clinically.

A study has 100 matched pairs. A matched pair, in the study’s context, is defined as a Hispanic patient matched with a non-Hispanic patient; the variables matched on are sex and age.

Within each pair, the following variables are collected for each patient:

Left lung functional residual capacity, FRC (lung specific variable)

Right lung functional residual capacity (lung specific variable)

Height (patient-level)

Smoking Status (patient-level, coded 0 or 1)

Family History of Respiratory Disease (patient-level, coded 0 or 1)

In a conditional logistic regression model, which I have continuously seen for the matched-pairs design, an outcome variable would be a binary variable indicating case or control, or absence/presence of disease (instead of ethnicity as highlighted in this example).

However, in setting up a regression model with matched-pairs data from the study, can a multiple linear regression model be used to answer the below question?

Is functional residual capacity (considered as an outcome variable) associated with smoking status, once the model adjusts or accounts for other assigned predictors, such as height and family history?
For example, in thinking about the continuous variables and categorical variables (all binary), difference variables may be calculated:

Left_FRC_diff = Left lung functional residual capacity (FRC) of Hispanic patient - Left lung of non-Hispanic patient

Right_FRC_diff = Right lung functional residual capacity (FRC) of Hispanic patient - Right lung of non-Hispanic patient

Without using a conditional logistic regression setup, is it statistically feasible to carry out a linear regression model in which the responding, or output, variable is a FRC difference variable and the predictor variables are other difference variables (please see below)?

Height_diff = Height of Hispanic patient - Height of non-Hispanic patient

Smoking_Status_Diff = Smoking_Status of Hispanic patient – Smoking_Staus of non-Hispanic patient

FamHis_Diff = Family History of Hispanic patient – Family History of non-Hispanic patient

However, in the case of repeated measures (FRC_difference variables), a generalized estimating equation (GEE) model must be used. In identifying a cluster to contain each non-Hispanic-Hispanic pair’s measures, I was thinking of a group ID variable for each pair; thus, there would be Left_FRC_diff and Right_FRC_diff measures for this cluster or unit organization. I was wondering if any other approaches existed for working with the lung-specific variables given the matched-pairs design.

Thank you for any help.